# What is the best way to do a route in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm a bit of a beginner at javascript but I am using next routes which uses path-to-regexp under the hood.

I have a page that has a list of links. The route for this page is `/locations/s-:specialty-providers` with "specialty" being the only dynamic part.

When I click on one of the links on the page, it reroutes me to `/locations/s-s-:specialty-providers/:abbr` (where both specialty and abbr are dynamic) when it should be rerouting to `/locations/s-:specialty-providers/:abbr`.

Routes file:

`{
    name: 'sitemap-providers-location-procedure',
    page: 'sitemap/providers/by_location/by_procedure',
    pattern: '/locations/:procedure-providers'
  },
  {
    name: 'sitemap-specialties-location-city',
    page: 'sitemap/specialties/by_location/by_city',
    pattern: '/locations/s-:specialty-providers/:abbr'
  },`

Answer (score 0):

**Next.js** will give you routing out of the box with putting your file in `pages` directory

Let's say you have `pages/index.js`

```
    import Link from 'next/link'

function getSitemaps () {
  return [
    {
      id:"1",
      title: "sitemap-providers-location-procedure",
      s: "providers",
      abbr: "by_procedure",
    },
    {
      id:"2",
      title: "sitemap-specialties-location-city",
      s: "specialties",
      abbr: "by_city",
    }
  ]
}

const SitemapLink = ({post}) => (
  <li>
    <Link as={`/sitemap/${post.s}/by_location/${post.abbr}`} href={`/sitemap?title=${post.title}`}>
      <a>{post.title}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
)

export default () => (
<div>
  <h1>Links</h1>
  <ul>
    {getSitemaps().map((sitemap) => (
      <SitemapLink key={sitemap.id} post={sitemap}/>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
)
```

and there is another file`pages/sitemap.js`

```
    import {withRouter} from 'next/router'

const Page = withRouter((props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{props.router.query.title}</h1>
    <p>This is the page content.</p>
  </div>
))

export default Page
```

Now you have that dynamic routes.

You don't need any magic or pattern in next.js to create route.

Comment: is that answer helped you?